# Close parent window / stop propagation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm too js-illiterate to figure this out. I have a fullscreen iframe acting as a modal, with a close button in a content div; now I want to apply that same closing function to the background without including the content div.
I currently call the function inline on the close button div like this:

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    <div id="closeButton" onClick="parent.$.fancybox.close();">
      &times;
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I can apply the same function to the background div but then everything on the content div closes the modal.

As I understand I have to use stopPropagation but I don't know where/how to include it.

edit: Here's more context. I would like to apply the same closing function as in #closeButton to #wrapper without affecting #content. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more code here.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="closeButton" onClick="function(e){e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox.close();}">
```

Comment: #closeButton was already fine (but with this code it stopped working) what I want is to make #wrapper close the iframe but to keep #content clickable without closing the iframe.

Comment: change preventDefault to stopPropagation

Comment: Thanks, I did that and applied it to #wrapper but the close function didn't work.